# HttpRequest object is null in response from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

This is my Azure function:

```
    [FunctionName("CreateItem")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string CompanyId = req.Query["CompanyId"];
        string Table = req.Query["Table"];
        string RowId = req.Query["RowId"];
        string Key = req.Query["Key"];
        string Action = req.Query["Action"];
        string Arg = req.Query["Arg"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
```

When I look at the requestBody objcet in runtime, it is null. Why Is that?

Comment: Are you `POST`ing data for the request body to capture?

Comment: Yes I am posting

Comment: I've recreated your function locally with a query string and a body, both work fine. It's likely your request isn't actually passing a body, just the query string. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. There is actually no Body at all. Because data come as parameters.

Comment: Feel free to send an answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [James Gould](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4664094/james-gould) and [Kresten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2814552/kresten). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> The Actual request was not passing the body. Its just passing the
> query string. That's the reason why requestBody objcet in runtime is
> null